# How create folder inside sub-domain from main domain

Tags: php, mkdir

How can i make folder from main domain like `www.example.com` to subdomain like `test.example.com` with php.

I try before `mkdir("upload/pic_245",0777)` on main domain work but when i try this it doesn't work :

```
mkdir("http://test.example.com/upload/pic_245",0777)
```

Comment: `mkdir` can't works with `http` wrapper. Which error did you get when you tried with `mkdir("upload/pic_245",0777)`?

Comment: with mkdir("upload/pic_245",0777) i have not any error but when use absolute link for create folder on subdomain i have issue.